# Localization in MVVM cross not working in xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, localization, mvvmcross

I used the following URL to implement localization in my application. It is using [MVVMCross framework in xamarin.

https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2017/12/30/mvvm-cross-with-xamarin-platform-resx-localization/

However, the application is not working for iOS. I followed the exact approach. The code works fine for android part. It is able to read AppResources.en.resx in iOS however it isn't able to read AppResources.es.resx file. When i change my device language to Spanish, it is taking the string of AppResources.en.resx and also not taking AppResources.resx(The default one)! You can follow the steps given in the link to reproduce the issue.

Is there anything I am missing out or doing wrong. Please let me know!

Comment: What kind of problem do you encounter ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! `the application is not working for iOS` is currently very broad; there can be numerous reasons as to why, but how are we supposed to replicate the issue if there is no code in the question?

Comment: My guess is that you are missing a nuget package in your iOS project.

Comment: @Woj I have added MvvmCross.plugin.Resxlocalization as given in the link.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I have edited the question. you can replicate the issue while going through the link provided in the question.

Comment: @Jet When I change my language to Spanish, it is reading AppResources.en.resx file string in iPhone. The same code is running fine for the Android part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the language was set to english in the info.plist. That's why it couldn't take the other languages. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/jsonlocalisation  instead of that ResxLocalization plugin which has so many issues while implementation specially with latest mvvmcross version

use below example to understand the json localization implemented here
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/Babel

If anyone need any help let me know have implemented it for Xamarin native android project